# Determining if a vector is in the Image of Matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The vector $u$ and matrix A is the following: $$u = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\\ -1\\2\end{pmatrix}$$ $$A = \begin{pmatrix}-1&3 \\\ 2&-4\\-1&-0 \end{pmatrix}$$

How do I calculate if the vector $u$ is in the image of A?

Comment: Apologies, after reviewing the question again I noticed it did in fact reference a vector, $v_1$ that can be used to calculate $Av=u$. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

$u$ is in the image of $A$ if there is an $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $Ax = u$. Can you solve the system $Ax = u$?

Answer (score 2):

This means the column vectors of the matrix
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}-1&3 &1\\\ 2&-4&-1\\-1&-0 &2\end{pmatrix}$$
are linearly dependent, i.e. $\det B=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the equations given by $A\cdot(x,y)=u$
If the system of 3 equations in two variables have a solution the vector $u$ is in the image

Answer (score 1):

You just need to find whether or not there is a vector $x$ such that $Ax=u$

$x$ must be a vector of two components, since otherwise the product $Ax$ would make no sense. Just call $x=(a,b)$ and solve the equations you get

Comment: Did you mean $\color{red}v$ where you wrote $u$ in the second paragraph?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I absolutelly did!